RXJS Обработка первого успешного потока
Есть три rxjs потока с разными setTimeout: 4000, 1000, 15000, в них вывод в консоль (log: Поток выполнен через <сек>), необходимо продублировать результат первого успешного (Через «сек›, выполнен первый поток)
То есть результат будет такой:
log: Поток выполнен через 1 сек.
log: Через 1 сек., выполнен первый поток
log: Поток выполнен через 4 сек. 
log: Поток выполнен через 15 сек.

